# littleproxy receive only DefaultHttpResponse impl of HttpObject

Tags: little-proxy

I am using littleproxy for analize responses in my app, there is my extension of HttpFiltersAdapter class where i override **proxyToClientResponse** method, input parameter for method is HttpObject

HttpObject has several extension classes - DefaultLastHttpContent, DefaultFullHttpResponse, DefaultHttpContent, DefaultHttpResponse (probably exist more classes but in prervious tests i saw only these), but now i get only DefaultHttpResponse which has not content field although my responses has content(i use my mock server for responses, and use other not my links for test via charles proxy)

other link, for example
http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/examples-of-html-1233547

What may be wrong with it? i need get content from response
or what is way to get content from DefaultHttpResponse(сast to other types with content is inpossible)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `getMaximumResponseBufferSizeInBytes` in your HttpFiltersAdapter. For instance

`@Override
    public int getMaximumResponseBufferSizeInBytes() {
        return 512 * 1024;
    }`